# C# Object Creation Takes Time

Tags: c#, object, creation

I need to create about 720 buttons or labels in my application during run time.
The problem here is when I start my app or make it (re-)visible, I can see that 
buttons being loaded.

How can I avoid from it or make it faster?

Comment: What on earth are you doing that needs 720 buttons?

Comment: You shouldn't try to reduce the time it takes to create one button. Instead, reduce the number of buttons. That looks like a real design flaw.

Comment: Are you using Forms or WPF?

Comment: Can you explain what are you doing, maybe there is better way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use [Control.SuspendLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx) Method before you've started to fill your control with buttons and than [Control.ResumeLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resumelayout.aspx) after you finished

Comment: +1 Only person to actually answer OP's question (everyone else so far has more or less commented on whether he has a good design or not, things that should go in the comment section...)

Comment: @marr75 - I agree but this **is** a textbook [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: Absolutely. Questioning his design and asking for more information are both perfect items for the comment section, though (granted, the investment of the respondent is significantly higher if he has to walk the OP through the question and then answer it).

Answer (score 2):

You could try suspending the layout before loading the controls, and resuming it afterwards.  This should speed the loading:  [SuspendLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx)

Here's a link which might prove useful reading: (tips on improving wndows forms apps performance) -

[Winforms performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163630.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It's hardly possible that you need **all** that buttons *at once*.

If ou're designing UI, split it in tabs, where tab rapresent UX logical groups.

If you're *not* designing UI, using control is not a good option, choose something else to *draw* on the screen and it will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good tips here you can go through to speed up your application.

http://devcomponents.com/blog/?p=361

That said, I would really raise a question on why exactly you need to load 720 buttons. There's a very good chance that you will only be using say 5% of the available controls on your form. Find out a good way to reduce them.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to "hide" the process of loading all the controls just use a splash screen so the user can see that the application is loading but cannot see all the actual components until the loading is done.

PS: Think about splitting those buttons in groups because i`m sure you don`t need all of them at one place(maybe split in tabs? and load them when the tab is pressed?) Well just think about it.